# TensorFlow dropout: how to apply different values to Train vs Test?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement **dropout in TensorFlow** for a simple 3-layer neural network for classification and am running into problems.  More specifically, **I am trying to apply different dropout parameter `pkeep` values when I train vs. test.**

I am taking the approach as follows:

1) def create_placeholders(n_x, n_y):

```
X = tf.placeholder("float", [n_x, None])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [n_y, None])   
pkeep = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
return X,Y,pkeep
```

2) In the function forward_propagation(X, parameters, pkeep), I perform the following:

```
Z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W1, X), b1)
A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)
A1d = tf.nn.dropout(A1, pkeep)
Z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W2, A1d),b2)
A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)
A2d = tf.nn.dropout(A2, pkeep)
Z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W3, A2d),b3)

return Z3
```

3) Later when tensorflow session is called (in between code lines omitted for clarity):

```
X, Y, pkeep = create_placeholders(n_x, n_y)

Z3 = forward_propagation(X, parameters, pkeep)

sess.run([optimizer,cost], feed_dict={X:minibatch_X, Y:minibatch_Y, pkeep: 0.75})
```

Above would run without giving any errors.  However, I think that the above would set `pkeep` value to 0.75 for both training and testing runs.  Minibatching is done only on the train data set but I am not setting the `pkeep` value anywhere else.

I would like to set `pkeep = 0.75` for training and `pkeep = 1.0` for testing.

4) It does give an error when I do something like this:

```
x_train_eval = Z3.eval(feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train,  pkeep: 0.75})

x_test_eval = Z3.eval(feed_dict={X: X_test, Y: Y_test,  pkeep: 1.0})
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_2 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

**What is the best way to pass different `pkeep` values for training and testing?**  Your advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some operation for testing defined as `test_op` (for instance, something that evaluates accuracy on input data and labels), you can do something like this:

```
for i in range(num_iters):
    # Run your training process.
    _, loss = sess.run([optimizer, cost],
                       feed_dict={X:minibatch_X, Y:minibatch_Y, pkeep: 0.75})
# Test the model after training
test_accuracy = sess.run(test_op,
                         feed_dict={X:test_X, Y:test_Y, pkeep: 1.0})
```

Basically you aren't testing the model when you are training it, so you can just call your `test_op` when you are ready to test, feeding it different hyperparameters like `pkeep`. The same goes for validating the model periodically during training on a held-out dataset: every so often run your evaluation op on the held-out dataset, passing different hyperparameters than those used during training, and then you can save off configurations or stop early based on your validation accuracy.

Your `test_op` could return something like the prediction accuracy for a classifier:

```
correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(predict, 1))
test_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
```

where `y` are your target labels and `predict` is the name of your prediction op.

Comment: Thank you Engineero.  That was very helpful.  I got it to work.

Comment: @BrightOrange great! If any of the answers helped, please mark it as correct so that people with the same problem in the future know what worked for you.

Comment: If marking it as "correct" means marking the "answer as helpful," I was told that I need at least 15 reputation points to do that.  As soon as I accrue 15 points, I will come back and do so.  I just joined yesterday =)  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In neural networks, you forward propagate to compute the logits (probabilities of each label) and compare it with the real value to get the error.

Training involves minimizing the error, by propagating backwards i.e. finding the derivative of error with respect to each weight and then subtracting this value from the weight value.

Applying different dropout parameters is easier when you separate the operations needed for training and evaluating your model.

Training is just minimizing the loss:

```py
def loss(logits, labels):
    '''
    Calculate cross entropy loss
    '''
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=labels, logits=logits)
    return tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='loss_op')


def train(loss, learning_rate):
    '''
    Train model by optimizing gradient descent
    '''
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name='train_op')
    return train_op
```

Evaluating is just calculating the accuracy:

```py
def accuracy(logits, labels):
    '''
    Calculate accuracy of logits at predicting labels
    '''
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
    accuracy_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32),
                                 name='accuracy_op')
    return accuracy_op
```

Then in your Tensorflow session, after generating placeholders and adding necessary operations to the Graph etc. just feed different `keep_prob_pl` values into the run methods:

```py
# Train model
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x_pl: x_train, y_train: y, keep_prob_pl: 0.75}})

# Evaluate test data
batch_size = 100
epoch = data.num_examples // batch_size
acc = 0.0
for i in range(epoch):
    batch_x, batch_y = data.next_batch(batch_size)
    feed_dict = {x_pl: batch_x, y_pl: batch_y, keep_prob_pl: 1}
    acc += sess.run(accuracy_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)

print(("Epoch Accuracy: {:.4f}").format(acc / epoch))
```

Comment: Thank you Soph.  Your detailed answer helped me understand Engineero's commments below.  I was able to get it to work =)